# Swift - Weird coding-compliant error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

I'm having a problem and I couldn't find anyone else on the web with the same struggle, maybe it's just too silly.

I have the following class:

```
class UIXOColourPicker : UIView {
    @IBInspectable var moodValue: Int!
    ...
}
```

And in my storyboard I have a view just like this:

[image]

The user defined runtime attribute was generated by Xcode IBInspectable functionality (which is really cool btw), but whenever I try to run the app I get the error

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIXOColourPicker 0x7fa86877c420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key moodValue.'`

I'm on Xcode 6 - Beta 6.

Any ideas?

Sorry if it's a silly question, but I've been struggling with it for like 2 hours and I don't have any other Swift developer here to have a look at it.

Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@IBInspectable` uses cocoa objects and not native swift types. So, anything that isn't implicitly convertible to a swift type needs to be a cocoa object instead. For `Number` or `Bool` you'd need `NSNumber`. For something like `Point`, `Size`, `Rect`, etc, you'd need to use `NSValue`. However, for `String` you can use `String` directly; you don't need to use `NSString`.

So, in your case, you need to use `NSNumber` instead of `Int`. I'd also use `NSNumber?` instead of `NSNumber!` in case the value isn't set in your storyboard/xib.

```
@IBInspectable var moodValue: NSNumber?
```

#### Update

As @JakeLin and @Echelon pointed out, for `int` like values, Xcode will only show the attribute in the Attributes Inspector if you declare it as an `Int?`, but then it will crash at runtime.  If you use an `NSNumber?`, it won't crash at runtime, but the attribute won't be available in the Attributes Inspector anymore; it will only show up in the User Defined Runtime Attributes (this seems like a bug in Xcode to me).

The error itself tells us how to get around that problem though:

> IBInspectable[66994:58722469] Failed to set (moodValue) user defined inspected property on (q25429792___IBInspectable.ViewController): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key moodValue.

What this is saying is that the runtime can't find a "key value coding-compliant" attribute on the class for `moodValue` (`Int` attributes aren't key value coding-compliant) and that you can implement `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` to fix that.

In that case, the implementation might look something like this:

```
@IBInspectable var moodValue: Int?

override func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forUndefinedKey key: String) {
    if let value = value as? Int? where key == "moodValue" {
        self.moodValue = value
    }
}
```

So, if you really want the attribute to show up in the Attributes Inspector and you don't mind adding the extra method, declare your property as an `Int?` and implement `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`.  If you don't want the extra method, you'll have to content yourself with using an `NSNumber?` and the User Defined Runtime Attributes UI.

Comment: @IBInspectable doesn't support `NSNumber`, it won't show up in Interface Builder.

Comment: I am really confused by this. @JakeLin is correct - when set to `NSNumber`, my `@IBInspectables` don't show up in the Attributes Inspector (only the raw key paths in the User Defined Runtime Attributes). When I use `Int`, they do show up, but they throw runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Echelon and @JackLin, I updated the answer with a different workaround that lets you use `Int` so that it'll show up in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 6):

This is down to your type for `moodValue`. It seems the KVO system can't handle the type coercion needed; it's looking for a `moodValue` with the actual type `NSNumber`. Changing

```
@IBInspectable var moodValue: Int!
```

to

```
@IBInspectable var moodValue: NSNumber!
```

Then picking out the `moodValue.integerValue` should do what you want.